# Does Browser load a whole block of JavaScript Before its execution?

Tags: javascript, function, scripting

Below is valid javascript code:

```
<script>
  foo();

  function foo()
  {
    alert("foo");
  }
</script>
```

The function foo is invoked before its declaration. So, I think browser must load the whole block script before its execution. By "whole block", I mean a open  tag to a clos  tag or a external javascript file. Is this true?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Answer (score 2):

[Function statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/function) are subject to *hoisting*. This means that regardless of where a function is declared, it is moved to the top of the scope in which it is defined.

```
(function () {
  foo();

  function foo() {
    alert('foo is beign called');
  }
}());
```

At compile time the structure of that code would change to:

```
(function () {
  function foo() {
    alert('foo is beign called');
  }

  foo();
}());
```

Function statements are not the only that are subject of hoisting, the [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/var) statement also, because of that (and because JavaScript haves only function-scope) is recommended to have only [one var statement](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#var) at the top of a function, for example:

```
var bar = "baz"; // on the outer scope
(function () {
  alert(bar); // bar is undefined

  var bar = "other value";
}());
```

The alert shows `undefined`, because internally the code changed to this:

```
var bar = "baz";
(function () {
  var bar;
  alert(bar); // bar is undefined

  bar = "other value";
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

If a method or variable is undefined, it throws an error "undefined" but if it is declared but not assigned a value then js won't throw any error.

```
<script>
  foo();

  function foo()
  {
    alert("foo");
  }
</script>
```

But your code will not throw any exception and also you can debug your javascript code easily. Here is a nice video shows how to debug js codes : [Debugging with Firebug](http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/screencast/firebug-js/)

Comment: No, no, no.
You can try it. In same block, you can use function before its declaration.

Comment: @Morgan : Sorry my mistake, I mistaken the function var hello = function(){} and function hello(). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I paste that JS into Firebug, I get "foo is not defined".

Most implementations of JS will *load* the entire file, and then execute it.  The statements in the file are executed in order, so the *call* to the function foo occurs before its *definition*, which is an error as required by the ECMA 262 standard section 8.7.1

Comment: @Berry, how do you paste it into Firebug?
You can paste it into a html and open it with Firefox. I bet it would work.

Comment: Firebug has a debug console, where you can execute custom code inside your own context.